# Generating Color Gradient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label

I want to display to my user how many (percent wise) of their forms are compliant with the new standard. The way I want to let them know visually is the percent amount will be colored. It will be 0xFF0000 (pure red) for 0% and 0x00FF00 (pure green) at 100%. What is the best way to calculate the color for each step along the way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668263/algorithm-question-need-to-dynamically-increment-from-00ff00-to-ff0000-over-time/669786#669786

Comment: Presumably the new standard isn't anything to do with accessibility, as some of your users won't be able tell the difference between red and green.

Comment: Yeah, green <-> red is going to be tough for people with colour blindness.

Comment: No, it's just how many users have emails on their form. The Red <-> Green isn't necessary, color blind people will still be able to see the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colour space conversion (as suggested by [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998280/generating-color-gradient/2998355#2998355)) will give you the best results.
If however this is beyond the scope of what you are looking for, I suggest a simple algorithm that gets you yellow (0xFFFF00) for 50 %:

For values up to 50 % Start with 0xFF0000.
Add 0xFF * Percentage / 50 to the green component.

For values above 50 % Start with 0xFFFF00.
Subtract 0xFF * Percentage / 50 from the red component.

The results  look good enough for my customers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate it yourself - try using a `LinearGradient` brush. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx))

```
LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
   new Point(0, 10),
   new Point(200, 10),
   Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0),   // Opaque red
   Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));  // Opaque blue

Pen pen = new Pen(linGrBrush);

e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 10, 200, 10);
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(linGrBrush, 0, 30, 200, 100);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(linGrBrush, 0, 155, 500, 30);
```